# Can't exclude imported Gmail messages when searching

Tags: gmail

I "pull"/"import" messages from another, non-Gmail email account (**notGmail@domain.com**) into my Gmail account (**gmail@gmail.com**).

I want to search for messages that *are* from either of two sender addresses (sender1@domain.com, sender2@domain.com) but were *not* addressed to **notGmail@domain.com**.  *Optionally* also not as BCC or CC, but that is *not* my priority.

I tried the following and variations of:

```
from:(sender1@domain.com OR sender2@domain.com) -to:notGmail@domain.com
```

(please notice the **-** as the **NOT** operator.)

but the Gmail search *still* returns emails originally sent to **notGmail@domain.com**

I cannot use **-**(notGmail@domain.com) because notGmail@domain.com **might** be mentioned in an earlier email somewhere.

Would anyone please have a solution to my quandary?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify that this is a pop account you are pulling mail from?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must be introducing a typo in your search.  Please make sure you are not using curly brackets {} as you did in your question

```
"I cannot use -{to_name@to_domain.com}"
```

Curly brackets are OR in Gmail so

```
from:(sender1@domain.com OR sender2@domain.com) -{to:notGmail@domain.com}
```

would not exclude to:notGmail@domain.com.

Your search should be

```
from:({sender1@domain.com sender2@domain.com}) -to:(notGmail@domain.com)
```

or a variation thereof and it will work.

```
{from:(sender1@domain.com) from:(sender2@domain.com)} -(to:notGmail@domain.com)

or

from:(sender1@domain.com || sender2@domain.com) -to:notGmail@domain.com

etc.
```

Please also note that Gmail can automatically apply a label to imported mail which gives you another easy way to filter: `-label:notGmail`